# Evaluating Lebesgue integral on the unit ball

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Does anyone can help me to calculate a Lebesgue integral with the help of the following definition?

$\int f d \mu = \int_0^{\infty} \mu(f^{-1}((t,\infty]))dt \in [0,\infty]$.

The integral to calculate is the following:
$\int_{B_1(0)} \vert x \vert^s d \mu(x)$
where $\mu$ denotes the n-dimensional Lebesgue measure and $B_1(0)$ the unit ball and $s \in \mathbb{R}$.

Is it possible here to work with the definition above?

Comment: First identify the set $f^{-1}((t,+\infty])$, then determine its measure, then integrate.

Comment: sorry but I am a bit stuck in indentifying the set $f^{-1}((t,+\infty])$. do I need a case by base observation?

Comment: Yes. First you need to distinguish the cases $s < 0,\, s = 0,\, s > 0$, and then $t = 1$ is a point where the behaviour changes.

Comment: do you mean the following? for example for s=0: $f^{-1}((t,+\infty]) = \{x: x<-t $ or $ x>t\}$. I am really stuck... :(

Comment: $f^{-1}((t,+\infty]) = \{ x \in B_1(0) : \lvert x\rvert^s > t\}$. Can you describe that set in words?

Comment: why x in the ball around zero?? ahhh because of the integration bounds, right?

Comment: in words: the x values in the unit ball around zero for which the function value is grater t

Comment: I meant a more geometric description. How does the set look, what is its shape?

Comment: sorry, I don't know how to illustrate that... :(

Comment: Take $n = 2$, then you can easily make sketches of these sets. Look at $s = 1$ and $s = -1$ to get the idea.

Comment: ok, for $n=2$: it is always (depending on $t$) 2 parts of the x-axis. bounded by + and -1. right?

Comment: No. It seems you don't know how to interpret $\lvert x\rvert$ for $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$. You need to look that up first.

Comment: does it have something to do with the p-norm?

Comment: depending on t, these sets a "rings"?!

Comment: For $s > 0$, yes. But the technical term in English is "annulus". For $s < 0$, these sets are (punctured) disks. In higher dimensions, the sets would be spherical shells ($s > 0$) and (punctured) balls ($s < 0$) respectively. Okay, then you need to find the inner and outer radius of these shells, or the radius of the ball. And know how the volume of such sets depends on the radii.

Comment: how does these ounctured disks or punctured balls look like?

Comment: Just like every disk or ball looks, except there's one point (the centre) removed. One can also call them annuli or spherical shells with an inner radius of $0$.

Comment: isnt it easy? the outer radius is 1 and the inner is t?

Comment: For $s = 1$, yes. It's not vastly more complicated for other exponents, but of course the result is different.

Comment: $t^{\frac{1}{s}}$? :)

Comment: Mhm how can I get the lebesgue measure of these sets Knowing the radii:)?

Comment: How does the measure of an $n$-dimensional ball depend on its radius?

Comment: $V_n (R) = C_n * R$ where $C_n = \pi^{n/2} / \Gamma (1+ n/2)$ and $R$ is the radius. right?

Comment: I suspect it's just a typo, but your formula isn't correct. (If you don't see it immediately, look at e.g. $n = 2$.)

Comment: oh: $V_n (R) = C_n * R^n$ :)?

Comment: Right. From that you can obtain the volume of a spherical shell (if you know the inner and outer radius), and thus you can compute your integral.

Comment: Am I right with this: $\mu (f^{-1}((t,+\infty])) = C_n * 1 - C_n*t^{1/s}$ with $C_n$ as above?

Comment: sorry for my questions divided into very small sections :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok I hope that I am now on a right way:

In order to usw the definition of the Lebesgue integral above I determined $f^{-1}((t,+\infty])$ as $\{ x \in B_1(0) : \lvert x\rvert^s > t\}$.
But in a next step, how can I get the measure of this set, i.e. $\mu(\{ x \in B_1(0) : \lvert x\rvert^s > t\})$?

Any suggestions :)?